# How to read and write file on flash drive

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4

I have a problem with my project. I want my project to read files from usb flash drive and be able to write data to flash drive in real time by plugging in a rasberry PI but I can't find any information on how to do it. Does anyone have a guide or a way to find information for me?

Comment: There is a fair number of tutorials that popped up with a bit of Googling. Are those resources insufficient?